# function returning pointer to struct slice only returns 1

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a function that basically looks like this:

```
func (db *datastoreDB) GetAllUsers(ctx context.Context) (*[]User, error) {
  query := datastore.NewQuery("User")
  var users []User
  _, err := db.client.GetAll(ctx, query, &users)
  return &users, nil
}
```

with the struct:

```
type User struct {
  username string
  password []byte
}
```

Now, if I try to call

```
users, err := models.DB.GetAllUsers(ctx)
log.Println(users)
```

then it will only print 1 user, even though there are many..

I tried to Print using users[0], users[1] but that returned errors, also tried with *users[1], &users[1], and `for i, _ range users { log.Println(users[i]) }`

Haven't quite been able to understand when/how to use * and & even though I read many online tutorials, so often just do trail and error.. I doubt there is anything wrong with my datastore GetAll function, so I assume I just fail to properly access/return the struct slice but feel like I tried everything..

Comment: this isn't the code you're using, because it can't compile. There's no reason for `GetAllUsers` to return a `*[]User`, just return the slice.

Comment: You might want to use `[]*User` so as to avoid copying the user every time you do something like `u := users[0]`, etc. And in cases like you have in your example you almost never want/need to return a pointer to a slice (`*[]User`), so just return the slice (`[]User`/`[]*User`) like @JimB already mentioned.

Comment: It compiled fine for me (but I of course also have package names, imports, datastore setup, main function, etc., (didn't want to paste a hundred lines of code).. but the problem was the `*[]User`.. after removing the pointer then it works, thanks a lot @mkopriva <3

Comment: @fisker: it compiles after you edit it ;) Don't do "trial and error" to figure out how pointers work, you're just going to end up in this situation over and over again. Pointers are very simple, just keep working through examples and it should click.

Comment: Yeah I did a recheck and noticed the missing &. I feel like I have read so many articles about pointers (and when I read them they make sense), but when I have to implement it myself then I'm not sure when to use and when not to use.. and then it ends up in the frustrating situation where I just try everything and hope something works. I have also gone through so much code on GitHub where they sometimes return function with `([]*User, error)`, while other times as `([]User, error)`, and I've pretty sure I've also seen it as `(*[]User, error)`

Comment: Similarly, sometimes it's written as `_, err := db.client.GetAll(ctx, query, &users)`, other times it's written as `_, err := db.client.GetAll(ctx, query, users)` (without the 'address of').. both ways appears to work just fine with `var users []User`

Comment: @fisker: trying to guess what type to use by copying other code isn't going to work. You need to understand _what_ a pointer is before it can make sense. If you look at the docs, the 3rd argument to `GetAll` _must_ be a pointer (like any other unmarshal/decode function), whether a `&` is required simply depends on the type of the variable. `[]*User`, `[]User` and `*[]User` and even `*[]*User` all have their uses, depending on the context and the type of `User`, you're not going to come up with an answer by looking at the syntax of other code, you need to look at _why_.

Answer (score 0):

Slices include pointers; in fact they are structs with a pointer to an array and some information as to where the slice *begins* and *ends*.

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment)

- [Golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

The asterix before a type designates that type as a pointer (unless it already is a pointer, in that case it *dereferences* it). I think you probably meant to write **`[]*User`**, which will expect a slice of **pointers to Users**. You can think of `[]` and `User` as distinct types.

To create a slice, the simplest way is probably with `make()`;

You can try, instead of `var users []User`,

```
users := make([]*User, 0) // replace 0 with the amount of nil values in the slice you're looking to fill
```

Finally, you'll have to remove the `&` signs you place before `users`, as these pass the pointer to a value (but as I *pointed* out above, slices are already pointers)

---

To better understand pointers, Dave Cheney recently wrote a blog post titled [Understand Go pointers in less than 800 words or your money back](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/26/understand-go-pointers-in-less-than-800-words-or-your-money-back), you might find it useful.